# Client Cannot Connect to Self-Hosted WCF Service Started with no BaseAddress

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I have created a service without giving the base address in the servicehost constructor.
and added the endpoint to host by calling AddServiceEndpoint method. In the AddServiceEndpoint method i am providing the complete address of the service. On the client proxy the call is failing with the exception as "There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8000/Test/TestService that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."
below is the sample code of ServiceHost and Client proxy

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Test.TestService)))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Test.ITestService),
    new BasicHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8000/Test/TestService");
    Console.ReadLine();
    host.Close();
}
```

Client Proxy:

```
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/Test/TestService");
ITestService proxy = ChannelFactory<ITestService>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(), ep);
string s = proxy.HelloWorld();
```

The line where I call proxy.Helloworld is failing and the exception comes.

But when I create the Servicehost with a base address, everything seems to work fine.
below is the code where i provide the base address in the servicehost constructor.

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Test.TestService),new Uri("http://localhost:8000/Test")))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Test.ITestService),
    new BasicHttpBinding(), "/TestService");
    Console.ReadLine();
    host.Close();
}
```

Can anyone answer what is going wrong here?
:
My Operation Contract  is as below:

```
[ServiceContract]public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string HelloWorld();
}
public class TestService: ITestService
{
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

The problem is I am not using any config file and when provide the base address in the servicehost constructor everything works fine but when i don't provide the base address in the servicehost constructor and provide the complete uri in the AddServicepoint method exception comes.

Answer (score 3):

Since you never call

`host.Open();`

in either of the code snippets shown in the question, I would not expect either of them to work.

Are you sure that you have posted the exact same code that is causing you the problem?

Comment: That answered my question. I was not calling the host.open in the second approach that's why the exception was coming. Thanks a lot.